# Can we define the dual of a set?

Tags: category-theory

In the wikipedia page of the category of sets, I see that this category is monoidal, and the tensor product of two sest is just the cartesian product.

My question is : can we define a "dual" of a set ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The notion of [dual](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dualizable+object) can be defined in any monoidal category, yes, and the unit is always dualizable, but it turns out that for the category of sets the unit object $1$ is the only dualizable object. More generally, if $\mathcal{C}$ is a [cartesian closed category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cartesian+closed+category) and $X \in \mathcal{C}$ is dualizable, then its dual must be $[X,1]$, which is just $1$, so that $X=1$ as well.